# How do you create a zip file after developing the module?

Tags: magento-1.9, plugin, development

I have been developing WordPress plugin since more than 5 years.

Since all files in WP plugin in one folder, it is very easy to create a zip file.

But it is very different in Magento. After I finish developing the module, how can I create a zip file? I mean my files are in so many folders, It is very difficult to collect them again.

So what method do you use to create a zip file after you develop the module?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way in magento to zip a extension. you need to create folder structure as per magento standard needs to move respective files in respective folder and make the zip file. there is no any tool for the same.

For example all your extension files is inside app/code/local/Vendor/Extension, theme files are inside app/design/frontend/rma/ then you need to create same folder structure and move your specific files to the folder and make zip mnually.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get all folders used in the plugin separate directory and name it what you want. Make sure all Files and folder present in the same order as per M-1.9 structure. like the following in one folder:

[image]

Under App:

[image]

In app folder you will copy your plugin from your development enviroment that might be under (app/code/local/vendor/moduleName or app/code/community/vendor/moduleName). Create its zip file and deliver it. User will extract it copy/paste it at root directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are main two way to create zip file.

1) create folder name it as your package name

- inside that create folder hirachy that your extension follow like create app->local->xyz

2) Using magento admin (recomended)

- you can follow [this link](https://www.brihaspatitech.com/blog/create-magento-extension-package-file/) to create it.
- This is [pdf file](http://info2.magento.com/rs/magentosoftware/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf) link that magento provides

Answer (score 0):

Apart from WordPress, in magento it's called Module.
For one click installation and activation of Magento module. You need to created a folder like

> App -> Code -> local -> VendorName folder -> ModuleName folder -> and
>   put your module files here
>
> then in same app folder create etc folder -> modules folder -> then
>   created VendorName_ModuleName.xml file

Now zip this app folder, once done. Its now ready to be used in other Magento 1.x installation, all you need to do is to, unzip this folder on the root your magento 1.x installation and it will add new files on their respective folder.